# Robot Framework/Selenium Script Fails to Execute Javascript on Salesforce Page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, salesforce, robotframework

I am working on automated testing using Robot Framework and Selenium for a Salesforce application. I have scripted a test case to login to Salesforce, navigate to the Opportunities page, and execute a JavaScript snippet to interact with an element on the page. However, I am encountering an error during the execution of the script. Here's a simplified version of my script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    Dialogs
Library    Telnet

*** Variables ***
${URL}        https://mycompany.lightning.force.com/lightning/page/home
${BROWSER}    Chrome
${USERNAME}   ****
${PASSWORD}   ****                 
${element}    xpath://a[@title='Opportunities']
${chrome_options}    add_argument("--incognito")

*** Test Cases ***
Open Salesforce Login Page
    ${chrome_options}    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --incognito
    Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}    options=${chrome_options}
    Title Should Be    Login | Salesforce
    Wait Until Page Contains    Username
    Input Text    id:username    ${USERNAME}
    Input Text    id:password    ${PASSWORD}
    Click Button    id:Login
    Wait Until Page Contains    Opportunities

Opportunity Creation
    Wait Until Page Contains Element   xpath://a[@title='Opportunities']   timeout=10s
    Execute Javascript    document.querySelector("a[title='Opportunities']").click();
```

When I run this script, it fails at the Execute Javascript step with the following error:

```
Opportunity Creation                                                  | FAIL |
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click')
  (Session info: chrome=118.0.5993.118)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF646798EF2+54786]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF646705612]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6465BA64B]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6465BF116]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6465C14AA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF646635394]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF64661BE6A]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF646634D02]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF64661BC43]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6465F0941]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6465F1B84]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF646AE7F52+3524194]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF646B3D800+3874576]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF646B35D7F+3843215]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF646835086+694166]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF646710A88]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF64670CA94]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF64670CBC2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6466FCC83]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FFDC169257D]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFDC2FEAA78+40]
```

I have verified the XPath locator and the JavaScript snippet, and both appear to be correct. I've also tried increasing the timeout for the page to load but the error persists.

I feel like in general, i have been having issues using testing frameworks with Salesforce.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this? Thank you in advance for your help!